# How to join multiple table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have 3 table

```
1- planes = name, description

2- presidents = id , p_name

3- plane_president = plane_id , president_id
```

how to join planes with presidents and plane_president?

```
  $planes = Plane::join('plane_president', 'planes.id', '=', 'plane_president.plane_id')
           ->join('presidents', 'presidents.id', '=', 'plane_president.president_id');
```

error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `planes` inner join `plane_president` on `planes`.`id` = `plane_president`.`plane_id` inner join `presidents` on `presidents`.`id` = `plane_president`.`president_id` order by `id` asc limit 10 offset 0)
```

Comment: the error is about the field `id` in you join statement (unlike what we see in your question) you must  be not using table name before it in your code. Anyway, try using the relation instead, it's way simpler as @Daniela answered

Answer (score 2):

`plane_president` is a pivot table for president and planes, you can declare the relationship at the `Plane.php` model:

```php
    public function presidents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
                President::class,
                'plane_president',
                'plane_id',
                'president_id');
    }
```

and use it like:

```php
plane->presidents;
```

when you want to retrieve the presidents for a particular plane in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 columns named id as the error says it is ambiguous.
`order by id asc limit 10 offset 0` here you aren't specifying by which column to order  planes.id or presidents.id

Comment: with presidents.id